# Can't render backbone view

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I have backbone view with inheritance:

```
class App.Views.User.Base extends Backbone.View
  el: '#main'

  initialize: ->

  events:
    'click .save': 'save'

  render: ->
    @$el.html @template user: @model
    @    


class App.Views.User.Registration extends App.Views.User.Base
  template: JST['template/users/registration']

  save: ->
    if not @model.expired()
      @model.save {},
        error: (model, response) ->
          console.log response.responseText
```

When I'm trying to render this:

```
(new FancySurvey.Views.User.Registration(model: model)).render()
```

I got the error:

```
Property 'template' of object #<Registration> is not a function
```

What might be a problem? Thanks

Comment: What is `@template` when `render` gets called?

Comment: @muistooshort, it's just undefined

Comment: And `JST['template/users/registration']` is a template function?

Comment: @muistooshort, thanks, because of your question i found the problem

Comment: Sorry to ask, but why this pseudo code and not the real deal? Should it remain in secrecy?

Comment: @dbf, it's real code, maybe you were thinking about javascript but here's coffeescript.

Comment: @dbf That may be the best review of coffeescript I've ever seen. ;-]

Comment: @megas Omg? How awesome is that? Screw JavaScript :D (not entirely, else coffeescript is useless ;))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with wrong path to template file, in my case it should be

```
class App.Views.User.Registration extends App.Views.User.Base
  template: JST['users/registration']
  ...
```